# Why does sunburn cause fever?

Tags: temperature, light, heat

Today I found out that sunburns can cause fever.

What I don't understand is how/why? In my understanding fever is the side effect of an immune reaction against an intruder, mainly bacteria (though I admit I can be wrong).

Google searches like "can sunburn cause fever" only bring up that it is possible, but not why.

Comment: Please don't comment I should see a doctor. I know. Also I had a hard time finding appropriate tags, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a good article on the topic.

https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/003227.htm

But it's most likely due to the fact that a sun burn is an actual burn on the skin that can cause inflammation, inflammation can in turn cause fever. Also having a really bad sunburn can open you up more to the possibilities of skin infections. If this happens then once again you might get a fever due to infection. If you really want to find out more on the cause of fever after sunburn you need to examine the pathophysiology of fever and why fever happens. I bet my money on fever due to skin inflammation after a sunburn, I guess the real question would be why does inflammation cause fever since sunburn = skin inflammation

Here is a good article

http://antranik.org/inflammation-and-the-pathophysiology-of-fever/

Comment: Mr Hons, you are right on the money; no need to guess. Here's a reference backing up your answer: [Ultraviolet Light Induces Increased Circulating Interleukin-6 in Humans](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022202X9090074G).